# Make loudspeaker active while making outgoing calls

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am trying to open a loudspeaker, whenever a call is made from android powered device. following is my code that i have used.:

MainActivity:

```
CallReceiver call = new CallReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        Main1Activity.this.registerReceiver(call, intentFilter);
```

Call receiver:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    AudioManager am;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        Toast.makeText(context, phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        boolean check = am.isSpeakerphoneOn();
        if (check) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "LoudSpeaker On: " + "Anchit",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Permissions in manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

i am not getting any error, but yes i am not able to make the loudspeaker work.

Please help.